# Can at least some parts of pgRouting run in parallel with parallel query?

Tags: postgresql, parallel-processing, postgis, pgrouting

### Objectives

I would like to run `pgr_dijkstra` for each pair of vertices in a routable graph. I have a simple script that takes each pair of vertices and launches a `pgr_dijkstra` against the database.

It would be nice to use [PostgreSQL parallel query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/parallel-query.html) capability to speed it up.

I would like to achieve an "easy" speed up without a need to implement advanced code like [contractions](http://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/contraction-family.html#contraction).

### Problem

Although I can see that for some of my tables `explain analyze` shows a plan that involves `Gather` and `Parallel Seq Scan`, trying to run `pgr_dijkstra` with "parallel" parameters enabled and with the `PARALLEL SAFE` keywords actually makes it slower.

### Input data

I have a PostGIS-enabled database with some `OSM` data imported with `osm2pgsql`:

| Data | Size |
| --- | --- |
| Nodes (vertices) table | 730 vertices |
| Nodes (vertices) table | 160 kB |
| Edges table | 1100 vertices |
| Edges table | 656 kB |

### PostgreSQL and system configuration

CPU: 11th Gen Intel Core i7-1165G7

| PostgreSQL parameter | Value |
| --- | --- |
| `min_parallel_table_scan_size` | 8kB |
| `force_parallel_mode` | off |
| `parallel_setup_cost` | 10 |
| `parallel_tuple_cost` | 0.001 |
| `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` | 8 |
| `max_parallel_workers` | 8 |
| `max_worker_processes` | 8 |

I have set `force_parallel_mode` to `off` as per [this recommendation](https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/using-forceparallelmode-correctly-postgresql), but even when `on` it does not make any difference.

Changing `parallel_tuple_cost` from the default value to `0.001` [does not seem to help](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2016/03/parallel-postgis-joins.html).

### Queries and results

I have set up a very simple `pgr_dijkstra` call with and without `SAFE`, with origin/destination vertices' `id`s hardcoded:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
FUNCTION pgr_parallel() 
RETURNS VOID 
AS $$
    BEGIN
    PERFORM pgr_dijkstra(
    '
      SELECT gid AS id,
        source,
        target,
        length_m AS cost
      FROM edges_table 
      WHERE
                        NOT source IS NULL
                        AND
                        NOT target IS NULL
                        AND
                        NOT the_geom IS NULL
                        AND NOT length_m IS NULL
    ',
    ARRAY[161]
    ,
    ARRAY[639]
   ,
    directed := false
    );
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
PARALLEL SAFE;
```

I have a simple script that calls this function N times, and it does not seem that it runs in a parallel way:

| Type of function | Number (N) of pairs of vertices | Execution time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| undefined (not parallel) | 50,000 | 67 seconds |
| `PARALLEL SAFE` | 50,000 | 89 seconds |

As an additional observation, I run `htop` and see that in the beginning, when the (parallel) script runs, all 8 physical cores are being used. But when the script finishes firing "tasks" to the database, `htop` shows that only one core gets used by the `postgres` process.

### Questions

If I understand correctly, a query can be 'parallelized' if there is some significant [independent work to be done by each worker](https://www.percona.com/blog/parallel-queries-in-postgresql/). In case of `pgr_dijkstra` and any other shortest path-finding algorithm, isn't this the case? I would suppose that `pgr_dijkstra` fetches vertices and edges and then runs an independent computation on them.

Is it possible to use the `parallel query` capability of `PostgreSQL` to make at least some parts of `pgr_dijkstra` to run in parallel? If yes, how?

*Note:* In [this post](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/routing-with-postgresql-and-crunchy-spatial) by Crunchy Data and Paul Ramsey, `PARALLEL SAFE` is used for a function that contains `pgr_dijkstra`, but there is no detail if it runs faster thanks to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `\df+ pgr_dijkstra;`, we see that the function is `parallel unsafe`, so no, you won't be able to parallelize it within a single query.

However you could try to run multiple queries in parallel (i.e. between different pairs of vertices), using multiple connections. Bear in mind that they will be competing for the same resources though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to function properties of `pgr_dijkstra`, it is indeed `parallel unsafe`. 

I wonder why then Crunchy Data [wraps](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/routing-with-postgresql-and-crunchy-spatial) `pgr_dijkstra` in a higher level function and marks it as `parallel safe`.

>> However you could try to run multiple queries in parallel (i.e. between different pairs of vertices), using multiple connections

This is exactly what I do. In the beginning all CPU threads are busy (probably the script polling the database via multiple connections), but then only 1 thread is used.